# Equation Labeling and xypic

Tags: align, xy-pic

Suppose I have the following TeX code for a diagram using xymatrix:

```
\begin{align}\label{diagram}
\xymatrix{
C\ar[r] & D &\\
B\ar[u] &   & \\
A\ar[u] &   &}
\end{align}
```

This creates a diagram with the equation label lining up with the first row, so it looks something like "C -> D (1)". How do I get it to line up with the B so that the equation label is aligned with the vertical center of the diagram?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest trick for having an `\xymatrix` centered with respect to the equation number is to enclose it into a `gathered` environment.

```
\begin{equation}\label{diagram}
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix{
C\ar[r] & D &\\
B\ar[u] &   & \\
A\ar[u] &   &}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

Don't use `align` for single equations (or, in general, single objects): the spacing comes out wrong.